# App Engine split application into modules

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the [new app engine modules feature](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) and I was trying to do a test drive with the [provided sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python) but when I'm pushing my modules with:

```
appcfg.py update app.yaml mobile_frontend.yaml static_backend.yaml
```

I receive the error:

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Your app may not have more than 2 modules.  Please remove one of the existing modules by deleting all of its versions before trying to create a new module.
--- end server output ---
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems that you need to enable billing in order to push more than 2 modules (I looked into quotas but didn't find info about this), also, I had billing enabled but it took sometime to become effective so if you're receiving the same error just wait a bit.